# Multiple inputs into a Single array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, arraylist

I need to find the greatest number in an array ,which gets it's inputs from the user and store it into the array variable .By comparing them with each number ,the largest can be found .
How to solve this problem ?

I tried by using map and split ()function using the input () type .After looping through the final array the array is not printing and returning the largest num .[Problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aX71o.png)

Comment: Fixed line 7: `array.append(int(input.strip()))`

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour] and read how to write a [mre]. Do not post images or links to code, post code. Put it in triple-backticks to take advantage of syntax highlighting. You also need to review the basic Python documentation in order to understand its syntax for basic constructs like for-loops. Also, take a look at [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max), it's a built-in and it will do the work for you once you get your input parsed.

Comment: Move line 11 above the previous line, and unindent it.

Comment: Fixed line 10: `for i in range(1, len(array)):`

Comment: Rename `arr` to`array`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by initializing a variable to keep track of the largest number read by input().

```
# vars
largest_number = 0
user_entry = 0
data = []

# ask user for n numbers (in this case 5)
for _ in range(5):
    user_entry = input("Enter a number to be added to the list: ")
    user_entry = int(user_entry) # convert to Integer
    if user_entry > largest_number: largest_number = user_entry
    data.append(user_entry)
    
# print results
print(f"Numbers entered: {data}")
print(f"The largest number is: {largest_number}")
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need to use an array?  A list might be better.  In any case here is a solution to your question.

```
import numpy as np
import random as rd

#Create an array
numarr =np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

#Take/make multiple user input and add it to an existing array
userinput=65
for i in range(userinput):
    randnum=rd.randrange(0,100)
    numarr=np.append(numarr, randnum, axis=None)
    

#Check to see if user input was added
print(numarr)

#Convert the array to a list
numarrlist=list(numarr)

#print the largest number
print(max(numarrlist))

#If you need the index location of the number in the original array
indexloc=np.where(numarr==(max(numarrlist)))
print(indexloc[0][0])

>>>[ 1  2  3  4  5 80  4  7 48 89  2 95  1  9 61 13 60 92 57 13 37 77 60 66 63 50 54 86 37 15 19 48 15 72 14 68  9 97  5  9 58 94 74 61 19 10 92 87 22 87  2  2 76 46 49 80 78 41 41 52 94 22 48 12 33 31 52 79 18 59]
>>>97
>>>37
```

This will return the array with your user's input, the largest number in the array and the index location of the largest number in the array.